# php search for work on specific url

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

i want to search for a word on example.com/page and if that word exist do nothing, if that word does NOT exist then send me mail via shell_exec

```
$command1 = exec("mail -s 'title' info@example.com  <<< 'message'");
$text1 = file_get_contents('http://example.com/page');
$intext1 = strpos($text1, 'tvshenja1') !== false; // note !==, not !=
echo $intext1 ? 'do nothing' : $command1;
```

i use this code but in whatever is the result  (exist or not exist) it send me mail

if i try with like this

```
 echo $intext1 ? 'do nothing' : 'word dont exist';
```

then it show me message word dont exist but when i try to use $command1 then in both cases it send message to my mail

Comment: the `$command1` variable contains the result of the `exec` function call (which sends you the email). You should run the `exec` command **only** if you found the text.

Comment: can u make an answer with correct code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$command1` variable contains the result of the `exec` function call (which sends you the email).

If you want to send the mail **only** if the text was found in the content of the page - you should call the `exec` function **only** in such case:

```
$text1 = file_get_contents('http://example.com/page');
$intext1 = strpos($text1, 'tvshenja1') !== false; // note !==, not !=

if ($intext1) {
    echo 'do nothing';
} else {
    echo exec("mail -s 'title' info@example.com  <<< 'message'");
}
```

Comment: i think u forgot ;

Comment: Sorry, missed a `;` after the first echo. Check the update and try again.